# Fetching same rows that has multiple columns along with other rows

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, plsql, postgresql-9.1

I have a view which results the following rows.

```
comp     Sub-comp   Lognum  id          Firname     LAstname

AK       AK-G       0       3897          ABC         DEF
AK       AK-G       0       5432          mark        ray   
MC       MC-A       0       1234          john        steve
MC       MC-A       0       5678          dan         pitcher
MC       MC-A       0       9843          james       robin
MC       MC-A       84      1234          john        steve
MC       MC-A       84      5678          dan         pitcher
MC       MC-A       84      9843          james       robin
```

I want to fetch the only the rows that has a lognum (if the same row has 0 also as lognum) along with the other rows that has just 0 as lognum.

The result table should be like this

```
comp     Sub-comp   Lognum  id          Firname     LAstname

AK       AK-G       0       3897          ABC         DEF
AK       AK-G       0       5432          mark        ray   
MC       MC-A       84      1234          john        steve
MC       MC-A       84      5678          dan         pitcher
MC       MC-A       84      9843          james       robin
```

And the outline of the query is as follows

```
create view view1 as
select 
comp, Sub-comp, "00" as Lognum,  id ,Firname ,LAstname
from
table A
inner joins---
UNION
select 
select 
comp, Sub-comp, Lognum, id ,Firname ,LAstname from 
table B
inner joins----
;
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: So you need the line with the bigger lognum?

Comment: sort of yes. I need only the row containing some value as lognum if the row has also 0 as lognum.

Comment: What database is this? Oracle or Postgres? Also, if you have multiple rows with the same `id` but a non-zero `lognum`, what do you show?  Only one of the rows or all of them?

Comment: Oracle. Only one of the row that has lognum

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from(
    select comp,
           Sub-comp,
           Lognum,
           id,
           Firname,
           LAstname,
           row_number() over(partition by id order by lognum desc) rn
    from table_name)
where rn = 1;
```

This will show the line with the biggest lognum grouped by the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work, even in cases where, for a given `id` value, you have multiple "non-zero" `lognum` rows.

If you look at the `where` clause, rows with non-zero `lognum` values are always returned (`t.Lognum != 0`). But rows with zero lognum values will also return, but only if the `t.rn = 1` condition is true, which will only happen if there aren't any other non-zero `lognum`s for that same `id` (see the `order by` clause of the `row_number()` window function).

```
select t.comp,
       t.Sub-comp, 
       t.Lognum, 
       t.id,
       t.Firname,
       t.LAstname
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by t.id
                     order by case when t.lognum = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as rn
          from your_view t) t
 where t.Lognum != 0 or t.rn = 1
```